# PHP speed test code

Tags: php, time

I want to see how long time it takes to my website to climb.

I tried this code:

```
    $timer = explode( ' ', microtime() );
    $timer = $timer[1] + $timer[0];
    print $timer;
```

But it shows that:

1309741766.46

- Note: And every two seconds it goes up.

For example: more two seconds It will be:

1309741767.46

And more two seconds:

1309741768.46

I will grateful for help.

Comment: Have a look at examples on `microtime` manuel page http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: For help in *what*? There is no question. PS: `microtime()` has *useful* argument ;-)

Comment: @stealthyninja - you should well be aware of climbing.  Liking hiding in trees and on rooftops.  I've often had ninja pages that were very adept at climbing trees and hiding in their foliage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the word you've said, but...

```
$start = microtime(true);
echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

Answer (score 2):

`microtime` returns a string containing microseconds and seconds. You are summing microseconds and seconds, which would lead to odd results.

`microtime` also inclues a get_as_float parameter which is likely what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to measure the in seconds:

```
$page_rendering_start_time = microtime_float();
...
...
...
$current_microtime = microtime_float();
$page_rendering_time_seconds = sprintf("%.4f", $current_microtime - $$page_rendering_start_time);

echo "Page rendering time: " . $page_rendering_time_seconds . " seconds";

function microtime_float() 
{ 
    list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    $microtime = (float)$msec + (float)$sec;

    return $microtime; 
}
```

It prints "Page rendering time: 0.0034 seconds"

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is only useful in PHP 4, as PHP 5 introduced the `get_as_float` parameter, as explained in Yann and webarto's answers.

Comment: 2 lonesomeday: My code works perfectly well in any PHP, there was abolutely no need to give me -1!!!

Comment: I didn't – I agree, it works in any version of PHP, but it's pointless (and slow) in PHP 5. It's the best solution in PHP 4.